# SoundCloud / Soundmanager2 Actionscript error

Tags: soundcloud, soundmanager2

The following (simple) code is triggering an error for some users, any idea what it could be and how to solve it (I'm letting the SDK load Soundmanager2)?

```
SC.initialize({ client_id: "clientID" });
SC.stream("/tracks/tracknumber", {autoPlay: true});
```

This is the error:

```
uncaught exception: Error in Actionscript. 
Use a try/catch block to find error.
```

Then it tries to load the sound from SoundCloud, but I guess the error prevents it from playing. This is only happening to some users (for example WinXP and Firefox), not all.

Since there were recent changes to the SC SDK, I'm not sure if there's a problem on their side (looking up the error message, I found some posts about Flash security settings over crossdomains).

Any idea about this?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

All indications point to a Flash JS access problem using the SC SDK, so I just started using Soundmanager directly, dropping the SC SDK. Problem solved!